# Python: Error using AST for lists in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings, ints and lists, let's call it listA

```
import ast
listA = "['0', '['0', '0']']
```

I want to convert this to a list

The expected result is `['0', ['0', '0']]`

When I run the following code to convert it to a list:

```
listA = ast.literal_eval(listA)
```

It returns a syntax error

```
>`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-6494c28ce5e6>", line 1, in <module>
    literal_eval("['0', '['0', '0']']")
  File "e:\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "e:\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    ['0', '['0', '0']']
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

Where have I gone wrong and how can I fix it?

Also, I have tried `listA = listA.replace("'", "\')` but the error is the same

Edit: (This is the code that forms the string listA)

```
listA = "['0', '0', 'a']"
before = "a"
after = ["0", "0"]
listA = listA.replace(str(before), str(after))
```

Comment: What is this supposed to be: `'['0'`... Its a string of a bracket, next to an int. The quotes must be escaped or alternated in order to allow the inner list to be parsed

Comment: @jacobIRR The whole inner list has ' around it

Comment: But how could any parser know where that string begins and ends, given the fact that a _closing quote_ appears after the first bracket?

Comment: `'['0', '0']'` is not properly formed.  There should not be quotes around the inner list.

Comment: The source of that list is not creating parse-able python code

Comment: So to fix it, I need a way to remove the quotes from around the inner list? If so, how can I write code to do this?

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld It would be much easier to fix it at the source so that they're not put there in the first place.

Comment: If you want `['0', ['0', '0']]`, the string should be `"['0', ['0', '0']]"`

Comment: `listA = listA.replace("'['", "['").replace("']'", "']")` - This is a dirty hack, just for this use case.

Comment: Let me add to my question to explain why there are quotes around the brackets, maybe there is an extremely easy fix there

Comment: The code has been added! @glibdud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the `a`, so the quotes around it remain. You should've replaced `'a'` (note the usage of `repr` instead of `str`):

```
>>> listA.replace(repr(before), str(after))
"['0', '0', ['0', '0']]"
```